# Container spins and exits immediately when on EC2

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a very basic application which writes to a file and since the writing to a file is in infinite loop the code doesn't exits. And I want this to be into a docker container and be into AWS.

**Local set up:**

I tried the solution in local and everything seems to be working fine. Below is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"c:\data\MyTest.txt";
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        string createText = $" {i} + Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path, createText);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Docker Commands:

```
 docker build -t test:1.0 .
 docker run -v c:\data {ImageID}
```

When I run above command, I am using `Docker Volumes` and I see a random folder getting create at `../docker/fasdfasdfas/_data` and I see `MyText.txt` continuously being written there and my `CONTAINER NEVER STOPS`.

So far so good

**Now AWS Steps:**

1. Uploaded the image to one of the Windows based EC2 instance.

Now when I run the same command

```
 docker run -v c:\data {ImageID}
```

the container starts and immediately stops. Not sure what's going on here.

**Docker file:**

```
# getting base image
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest

ADD ./bin/debug /exe/

ENTRYPOINT ["/exe/BackendService.bat"]
```

**BackendService.bat**

```
start c:\exe\ConsoleApp16.exe
```

I checked the logs and I do not see any issue there either

Answer (score 0):

In you dockerfile, `c:\data\` directory is not created.
If thats not the issue, log or print the error messages and then fire `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME` or `kubectl logs -p POD_NAME` to check for errors.